# error Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:./lib

Tags: vuejs3, npm-install

```
npm install

3134 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
3135 verbose argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3136 verbose node v16.11.0
3137 verbose npm  v8.0.0
3138 error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
3139 error Unsupported URL Type "workspace:": workspace:./lib
3140 verbose exit 1
```

Why????

Please!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVBZG.png)

After changing many versions, this error still occurs, and the version number of ""workspace" does not appear in the dependencies. I don't understand, please help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.